# Storing data to Java Collection from Excel file

Tags: java, excel, collections, hashmap, apache-poi

I'd like to read data from Excel file and would want to store into Java collection something like HashMap or something.

I've implemented Excel reading through Apache POI- That part is working pretty fine.
Now I'm wondering how to store that data into HashMap.

I've created 1 POJO class having values of Excel data.

```
Class EmpXcel
    private String emp_name;
    private String emp_job;

     // parameterised constructor

     // getter-setter
```

Now If I create the HashMap of type of this particular POJO Class.

For ex. `Map<String, EmpXcel> map =  new HashMap<String, EmpXcel>();`

This is my Code for reading data from Excel.

```
while(itr.hasNext()){
            Row nextRow = itr.next();
            // For each row, iterate through all the columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
            {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                switch (cell.getCellType()) 
                {
                    //  if cell is numeric format   
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue()+",");
                        break;

                    // if cell is string format
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + ",");
                        break;
                }
            } 
         System.out.println();
    }
```

I'm not sure How to store this data into HashMap of type POJO class(Here EmpXcel).

EDIT: Excel table:

```
Emp_Name |  Emp_Job

Travis   |  Technical Assistant

John     |  Professor
```

Also I'd like to make it more generic- want to create single Java class for different Excel files(irrespective of the no of rows/cols)

Please share me some of your insight so I can follow that way.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of data in excel?

Comment: Why do you want to use a HashMap? The order is not predictable.

Comment: @java8.being. String type...Question updated with Excel table sample

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis I'm not entirely sure which collection would be the better choice to implement

Comment: Can employee name be duplicated?

Comment: Seeing at the data doesn't seem like if you need a map at all. This can be extracted into a list as well

Comment: Yes not a single column is unique

Comment: I would use an ArrayList (List<EmpXcel> data = new ArrayList<EmpXcel>(); )

Comment: But Don't you think that for millions of records Map would be faster than List?

Comment: You don't have enough uniqueness to your data to have a key for the map. You could do a random UUID key, but that would be useless when trying to access the map. Do you really have millions of records?

Comment: No as of now its around 10k records. and If I implement ArrayList as you've suggested, how would I add records for each column into it.
For ex. _I read from Excel Emp_Name and Emp_Job- How am I supposed to add and in later point of time, retrieve?_>

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your last comment @inityk
By using getColumnIndex(), you can access all the cells and then can validate the data present in it.

```
List<EmpXcel> empXcelList=new Arrayist<EmpXcel>();
   while(itr.hasNext()){
        Row nextRow = itr.next();
        EmpXcel empXcelPOJO = new EmpXcel();
        // For each row, iterate through all the columns
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
        {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

            if(cell.getColumnIndex()==0) 
            {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    System.out.print("Name should not be numeric");
                    break;

                // if cell is string format
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    empXcelPOJO.setEmpName(cell.getStringCellValue())
                    break;
            }elseif(cell.getColumnIndex()==1) 
            {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    System.out.print("Name should not be numeric");
                    break;

                // if cell is string format
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    empXcelPOJO.setEmpJob(cell.getStringCellValue())
                    break;
            }
        } 
     empXcelList.add(empXcelPOJO);
    }
```

Comment: cell.getColumnIndex()==0 is same as nextRow.getCell(0)?
seems like both of them return or checks 1st cell.
Correct me if you think I'm wrong

Comment: +1 for pointing out validation!
Moreover, what I want to do I'd like to make single Java class for Mutilple excel files(irrespective of the count- How am I supposed to implement that)

Comment: Please explain more about the query above. like what do you mean by java class for multiple files?does it mean a single pojo class to store data for multiple excels containing different data or single processor for processing different excels are creating collection of java object out of them? please let me know which class you are talking about.

Comment: moreover, if two excels are containing different information all together then use different classes(POJO) to store the info. to use a single class for storing information, the column sequence should be same in excel.

Comment: Yeah, I felt the same- but Do we have any provision in POI to fetch the entire row and store all those values of a row into ArrayList or some other collection?

Comment: Actually , it is us who should store the cell values in variable of a POJO and create an appropriate collection to store and use the data. POI just allows you to read the data.